# How to get device info and pass it to repository

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, device-orientation

Here I want to get device info and after getting device info I want to pass it into my repository file so whenever I register my device info automatically saved.

in this code i want to pass device info in deviceinfo.

Here is some code i've tried

```
class SignupRepository {
  SignupRepository();

  Future<SignupUser> signupUser(Map<String, dynamic> signUpUserMap) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> signupUserRequestMap = {
      "user": {
        "email": signUpUserMap['email'],
        "password": signUpUserMap['password'],
        "mobile": "+918460666940",
        "statusId": "confirmation_pending",
        "profile": {"firstName": "Dipak", "lastName": "Savaliya"},
        "install": {
          "os": "iOS 11.3",

//Here i want to pass device info from device info class

          "deviceInfo": {"device": "iPhone 7 Plus", "manufacture": "Apple"},
          "deviceToken": "34214324213413423421",
          "fcmToken": "1234234234231423421423424234123"
        }
      }
    };
    final QueryResult result = await GraphQLHelper.gqlMutation(
        GQLStrings.signupUser(), signupUserRequestMap);

    SignupUser signupUser = SignupUser.fromJson(result.data);
    return signupUser;
  }


}
```

Here is Code of Device info getting. When i am run this code it will show me all device info which perfect. but i need to pass this device info in my repository class(repository class code is show above)

```
class _DeviceinfoState extends State<Deviceinfo> {
  static final DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfoPlugin = new DeviceInfoPlugin();
  Map<String, dynamic> _deviceData = <String, dynamic>{};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  Future<Null> initPlatformState() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> deviceData;

    try {
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        deviceData = _readAndroidBuildData(await deviceInfoPlugin.androidInfo);
      } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
        deviceData = _readIosDeviceInfo(await deviceInfoPlugin.iosInfo);
      }
    } on PlatformException {
      deviceData = <String, dynamic>{
        'Error:': 'Failed to get platform version.'
      };
    }

    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _deviceData = deviceData;
    });
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> _readAndroidBuildData(AndroidDeviceInfo build) {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'version.securityPatch': build.version.securityPatch,
      'version.sdkInt': build.version.sdkInt,
      'version.release': build.version.release,
      'version.previewSdkInt': build.version.previewSdkInt,
      'version.incremental': build.version.incremental,
      'version.codename': build.version.codename,
      'version.baseOS': build.version.baseOS,
      'board': build.board,
      'bootloader': build.bootloader,
      'brand': build.brand,
      'device': build.device,
      'display': build.display,
      'fingerprint': build.fingerprint,
      'hardware': build.hardware,
      'host': build.host,
      'id': build.id,
      'manufacturer': build.manufacturer,
      'model': build.model,
      'product': build.product,
      'supported32BitAbis': build.supported32BitAbis,
      'supported64BitAbis': build.supported64BitAbis,
      'supportedAbis': build.supportedAbis,
      'tags': build.tags,
      'type': build.type,
      'isPhysicalDevice': build.isPhysicalDevice,
    };
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> _readIosDeviceInfo(IosDeviceInfo data) {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'name': data.name,
      'systemName': data.systemName,
      'systemVersion': data.systemVersion,
      'model': data.model,
      'localizedModel': data.localizedModel,
      'identifierForVendor': data.identifierForVendor,
      'isPhysicalDevice': data.isPhysicalDevice,
      'utsname.sysname:': data.utsname.sysname,
      'utsname.nodename:': data.utsname.nodename,
      'utsname.release:': data.utsname.release,
      'utsname.version:': data.utsname.version,
      'utsname.machine:': data.utsname.machine,
    };
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text(
              Platform.isAndroid ? 'Android Device Info' : 'iOS Device Info'),
        ),
        body: new ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: _deviceData.keys.map((String property) {
            print('${_deviceData[property]}');
            return new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: new Text(
                    property,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                new Expanded(
                    child: new Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 10.0),
                  child: new Text(
                    '${_deviceData[property]}',
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                )),
              ],
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to just pass device info (eg: device name, manufacturer, model) because i have to store that device info with users signup detail into Database
Hope you understand and if not please let me know and please Help :) your help is very valuable for me

Comment: Yes but i am not able to pass. device info is in another class and when i am pass into it it will show an error.

Comment: Yes i also posted a device info class please check it

Comment: it doesn't show me the error but it does not suppose to allow me to pass it.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you are attempting to pass device info to your repository class?